# Fetch SQL data and send multiple emails with nodemailer?

Tags: mysql, node.js, nodemailer

So I am building this small emailing application to study node.js and mysql.

I have successfully stored data to mySQL database and I stored it like this

```
var emails = 'SELECT user_email FROM scrap';
con.query(emails, function(err, email, fields){
  //console.log(email);
});
```

The console.log shows

```
[ RowDataPacket { user_email: 'dummybot@gmail.com' },
  RowDataPacket { user_email: 'dummybot2@gmail.com' }, ]
```

I am currently using nodemailer to send multiple emails at once.

```
var mailOptions = {
  from: 'dummybot@gmail.com',
  to: emails,
  subject: 'Sending Email using Node.js[nodemailer]',
  text: 'That was easy!'
};
```

When I execute this command I receive an error

```
Error: No recipients defined
```

Is there an alternative way to send multiple emails at once? or is there a way for me to make sure my application send multiple emails accordingly to the emails from database(mySQL). I would like to make sure the app sends reply to all emails stored in the database.

Comment: Following the solution on this URL at the moment but failing... :( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28527561/sending-email-to-multiple-recipients-via-nodemailer

Comment: emails is stilled defined as 'SELECT user_email FROM scrap' in your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to get your recipient list into an array first.
can be achieved easily in a for loop. be careful not to get confused in your definition of emails and email as well.

```
var emails = 'SELECT user_email FROM scrap';
var to_list = []
con.query(emails, function(err, email, fields){
  //console.log(email);
  for(k in email){
      to_list.push(email[k].user_email)
    }
}); 

var mailOptions = {
  from: 'dummybot@gmail.com',
  to: to_list,
  subject: 'Sending Email using Node.js[nodemailer]',
  text: 'That was easy!'
};
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion I will try it out and let you out if it works!

Comment: So I tried your code perfectly! but I would like to know how to send multiple replies to all mails inside the database (There are multiple emails saved inside the database) - @Tik

Comment: what do you mean by multiple replies?

Comment: So i figured that if one person send multiple emails, only one email is replied. For example if dummy@a.com ask questio  twice, the function will only reply it once not twice.